# Move fields from additional settings to field_group on node edit forms

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I try to move some settings, for example the comment or menu settings, from the "additional settings" to my own field group created with the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

As there is no way to access the fields under additional settings via the gui I thought about moving them via a form_alter hook, but with no success.

**Update**

Here is the code i used in a custom module to (unsuccessfully) move a field:

```
function form_tweaks_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form']) {
    // Adding the comment settings to my field group
    $form['#group_children']['comment_settings'] = 'group_sidebar_tab4';
```

My module's weight is lower then the weight of the field group module and when I use the above code on other fields added to the content type, for example an image field, it works just fine.

**Update 2**

Just to make sure, I am talking about **node forms**. I want to move certain elements that resist in the "additional settings" vertical-tab-group to other groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good amount of researching I stumbled upon the [Renderable Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/rel) module.

It is still a bit experimental, but it makes a bunch of form elements available for rearrangement that are hard-coded in the node module and therefore not accessible via manage fields.

Answer (score 1):

[Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)

-module which changes the `manage display` page to allow exactly for that and moving title, links, comments and way more useful features like changing/resetting field and views templates, linking between displays, dynamic & block fields, moving fields to a block just to name a few. It could replace views in those cases where you mainly use views to have more control over the output.
Thank You.

Comment: But it doesn't allow to move fields from the "additional settings" group to other groups, does it?